# When i have to use Hibernate's rollback

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions

When i have to use Hibernate's rollback?
Hibernate will do rollback itself in exception case, so my `rollback` line just external:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

try {
session.beginTransaction();

test cl = (test) session.createCriteria(test.class)
.add(...)
.list()
.get(0); // Here's throws an exception, Hibernate was rolled back automatically.

session.getTransaction().commit();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
session.getTransaction().rollback(); // The transaction already was rolled back. Unnecessary?
}
```

That's the only approach to use Hibernate's rollback which i can invent but rollback has not sense there.

So in which cases i really have to use rollback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case there is no exception, but you still want to roleback because you found something wrong in your program logic, that's when you can use it. Like if you are updating multiple entities and your modified one and found some anomaly in the data according to your business logic, you can call rollback.